# Change nuxt-i18n locale with cookie on site load

Tags: internationalization, nuxt.js, vue-i18n

I've two locale; "fa" and "en" with fa being default. I've tried to change it with the following code block both on `nuxtServerInit` and `fetch` hook of layout but it still revert back to my default locale and gives me `json.parse` error on route change.

```js
// using "nuxt": "^2.15.8" , "@nuxtjs/i18n": "^7.2.0" , "@nuxtjs/universal-storage": "^0.5.9" , "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.12.3"
async fetch(){
  let locale = this.$storage.getCookie('localeLang')
  if(!!locale){
      await this.$i18n.setLocale(locale)
      this.$vuetify.rtl = this.$i18n.localeProperties.dir === 'rtl'
      this.$storage.setCookie('localeLang', locale, {maxAge: 315360000})
  }
}
```

When using in `fetch` hook i can see for a moment that it's in `en` then revert back to `fa` . but the `htmlAttr` of `meta` are set according to `en` locale (which has been set on cookie)

So what should I do? Any idea?

```js
// nuxt.config.js
i18n: {
    baseURL: process.env.DEFAULT_BASE_URL,
    locales:[
      {
        code: 'fa', 
        iso: 'fa-IR', 
        file: 'fa.js', 
        currency: {name:'تومان', sign:'ت'}, 
        dir: 'rtl', 
        name: 'فارسی', 
        initial: 'FA',
      },
      {
        code: 'en', 
        iso: 'en-US', 
        file: 'en.js', 
        currency: {name:'Dollar', sign:'$'}, 
        dir: 'ltr', 
        name: 'English', 
        initial: 'EN',
      },
    ],
    defaultLocale: 'fa',
    strategy: 'no_prefix',
    lazy: true,
    langDir: '~/locale/lang/',
    detectBrowserLanguage: false,
    // vueI18n: '~/plugins/vue-i18n.js',
},
```